# What is the Fourier Transform of an absolute function?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I would like express that the Fourier transform of the function
$$
|f(x)|
$$
as
$$
\widehat{|f|}(\xi) = \text{a function of } \widehat{f}(\xi)
$$
In fact, I want to know the relation of $\widehat{|f|}(\xi)$ and $\widehat{f}(\xi)$. 
I think a identity $|f|^2 = f \overline{f}$ may help.

Comment: I agree that the link given by @BLAZE is not related. I can also add that I've never seen some formula for the Fourier transform of the absolute value of a function in  terms of the Fourier transform of the function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\in L^1$, $f\ge0$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Define $f_a(x)=e^{iax}f(x)$. Then
$$
\widehat{f_a}(\xi)=\hat f(\xi+a),\quad \widehat{|f_a|}(\xi)=\hat f(\xi).
$$
There is no functional relation between the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $|f|$.